# Finding row with minimum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following input and I want to be able to translate it into the output. Really simple (in principle!) - just trying to find the min value of each row and then bring back the heading value in each column.

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rOEv.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlVx5.png)

How do I find the column heading that tallies to the minimum value as per the example?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html#pandas-dataframe-idxmin) with axis=1:

```
df.idxmin(axis=1)
```

This should return the column header of each row where the minimum value is found in that row.  In cases of duplicates it will select the first value.